# Put mapped elements reference in correctly ordered list

Tags: reactjs

I will be posting multiple types of `Block` components in a vertical list in random orders and conditions. The blocks will be placed according to list values where list items will be inserted or deleted at any time. I need to store the reference of all the blocks in the exact order of their position in the parent element. The list of the references of the blocks should also be updated when the elements get updated/removed.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

...

type Blocks = Block1 | Block2 | Block3;

interface Props {
  data: ListData[];
}

interface State {
  data: ListData[];
}

export default class Page extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  state: State;
  private blocks: Blocks[] = [];

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: props.data
    };
  }

  private addListDataItems(): void {} // Add `ListData` items randomly

  private removeListDataItems(): void {} // Remove `ListData` items randomly

  render(): JSX.Element {

    return <>
      <div className="page">

        {this.state.data.map((li: ListData, i: number) => <Fragment key={i}>

          {((i % 10) === 0) && <>
            <Block1
              ref={(e: Block1): void => {
                this.blocks[ /* Insert reference according to it's position in the parent element */ ] = e;
              }}
              ...
            />
          </>}

          {(
            // Some conditional Logic Here
          ) && <>
            <Block2
              ref={(e: Block2): void => {
                this.blocks[ /* Insert reference according to it's position in the parent element */ ] = e;
              }}
              ...
            />
          </>}

          {(
            // Some conditional Logic Here
          ) && <>
            <Block3
              ref={(e: Block3): void => {
                this.blocks[ /* Insert reference according to it's position in the parent element */ ] = e;
              }}
              ...
            />
          </>}

        </Fragment>

      </div>
    </>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on what you need to do exactly, I'd recommend simply avoiding having to construct an array of refs. Especially if your situation is complex with branching `if`s and a hard requirement for the order.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? I would recommend splitting the representation in html and data. Make an array of blocks ordered in the way you want based on input and render it always from this array. Basically to move as much logic as possible out of the render method.

Comment: Yeah sorry. My app is very complex with lots of different types of events (keyboard, mouse, inview etc). So the best logic I could think of was to get a guaranteed ordered list of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would probably depend on what you need to do with the references afterwards. Since you're looking for an array in order, I'm going to assume you'll need to iterate over them top to bottom.

I'd propose a sparse array as your best option here: each `ListData` item in the `this.state.data` array can result in 0, 1, 2, or 3 `Block` being added to your array, so the resulting sparse array of refs could look like `[ref, ref, undefined, ref, undefined undefined, ref, ref, ref, ...]`.

To obtain that array, simply use a multiple of `i` as your index:

```
{this.state.data.map((li: ListData, i: number) => <Fragment key={i}>
  {/* condition */ && (
    <Block1 ref={(e: Block1) => this.blocks[i * 3 + 0] = e} />
  )}
  {/* condition */ && (
    <Block2 ref={(e: Block2) => this.blocks[i * 3 + 1] = e} />
  )}
  {/* condition */ && (
    <Block3 ref={(e: Block3) => this.blocks[i * 3 + 2] = e} />
  )}
</Fragment>)}
```

Don't forget to also reset your ref array at the top of the render function to avoid preserving old refs when re-rendering.

```js
render() {
  this.blocks = []
  // ...
```

And when you need to iterate over your blocks, just skip the falsy ones:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.blocks.length; i++) {
  if (!this.blocks[i]) continue
  // actual code
}
```

```js
for (const block of this.blocks) {
  if (!this.blocks[i]) continue
  // actual code
}
```

Or use array functions since they already skip empty elements in a sparse array:

```js
this.blocks.forEach(block => {
  // actual code
})
```

```js
this.blocks.map(block => {
  // actual code
})
```

---

Clarification: I represented a sparse array as having either a `ref` or `undefined` in each item, but a *sparse array* is an actual thing in JS when an item hasn't been defined *ever* (or has been `delete`d). And the console representation of a sparse array looks like this

```bash
[ ref, <1 empty item>, ref, <2 empty items>, ref ]
```

Comment: I used your logic very late (just before the bounty expired) but is getting me an ordered list. I will further see if I ever run into any issues.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would probably depend on what you need to do with the references afterwards. Since you're looking for an array in order, I'm going to assume you'll need to iterate over them top to bottom.

If you need to have a compact (regular) array, you should try and think more in JavaScript terms and less React. React is just JS after all.

For example, you could have a counter to remember the indices of your array:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
  let cursor = 0
  const blocks = []
  this.blocks = [] // resetting in case array size changes
  this.state.data.forEach((li, i) => {
    if (/* condition 1 */) {
      blocks.push(<Block1 key={i+'1'} ref={e => this.blocks[cursor] = e} />)
      cursor++
    }
    if (/* condition 2 */) {
      blocks.push(<Block2 key={i+'2'} ref={e => this.blocks[cursor] = e} />)
      cursor++
    }
    if (/* condition 2 */) {
      blocks.push(<Block2 key={i+'3'} ref={e => this.blocks[cursor] = e} />)
      cursor++
    }
  })

  return <>
    <div className="page">
      {blocks}
```

Or if manipulating JSX outside of the return of the render function is too odd looking, you could just compute the conditions beforehand

```
render(): JSX.Element {
  const blocksData = this.state.data.reduce((array, li, i) => {
    if (/* condition 1 */) {
      array.push({ Element: Block1, index: array.length })
    }
    if (/* condition 2 */) {
      array.push({ Element: Block2, index: array.length })
    }
    if (/* condition 3 */) {
      array.push({ Element: Block3, index: array.length })
    }
    return array
  }, [])

  this.blocks = [] // resetting in case array size changes
  return <>
    <div className="page">
      {blocksData.map(({Element, index}) => (
        <Element ref={e => this.blocks[index] = e} />
      ))}
```

Comment: The accepted answer worked so I didn't bother to test this out. This might be a good solution too :)